# ClassNotFoundException for android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder

Tags: android, eclipse, android-notifications, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to trigger/display a notification but when I do the app fails with:

```
02-06 21:25:03.408: E/AndroidRuntime(21469):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder
02-06 21:25:03.408: E/AndroidRuntime(21469):        at     java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-06 21:25:03.408: E/AndroidRuntime(21469):        at     java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
02-06 21:25:03.408: E/AndroidRuntime(21469):        at     java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
02-06 21:25:03.408: E/AndroidRuntime(21469):        at     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
02-06 21:25:03.408: E/AndroidRuntime(21469):        ... 12 more
02-06 21:25:03.408: E/AndroidRuntime(21469):    Caused by:     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Manifest uses-sdk:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Code:

```
    final Context ctxThis = this;
    btnAsleep.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            boolean isAsleep = SleepDeterminator.getSleepDeterminator().isAsleep();
            txt.setText("Asleep: " + isAsleep);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctxThis)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!");

        }
    });
```

There is a file called 'android-support-v4.jar' in my libs folder that contains the class.

I tried the solution found elsewhere with properties>java build path>Order and Export and export private libraries etc (all are exported right now).

I have not found any related errors using the Lint tool.

I have installed the SDK-Build tools for v19. (I tried other sdkVersions too (16, 21)

I have tried "fix project properties".

I have tried "add support library" - it adds the android-support-v4.jar (for some reason asks me to agree to the licence every time).

I'm developing in Eclipse Juno, x64 on Windows, JDK 1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to clean the project. I dis- and re-enabled automatic build.